# onchange update gender javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My code doesn't work. When I change value of the `gender` select tag, the table doesn't update. `Address` works fine

```
$(document).on('blur', '.address', function(){  
    var id = $(this).data("id4");  
    var address = $(this).text();  
    edit_data(id, address, "address");  
}); 

$(document).on('change', '.gender', function(){  
    var id = $(this).data("id5");  
    var gender = $(this).value();  
    edit_data(id, gender, "gender");  
}); 

function edit_data(id, text, column_name) {  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "edit.php",  
        method: "POST",  
        data: {
            id: id, 
            text: text, 
            column_name: column_name
        },  
        dataType: "text",  
        success: function(data) {  
             alert(data);  
        }  
   });  
}
```

edit.php:

```
<?php  
    include 'database/connect.php';
    $id = $_POST["id"];  
    $text = $_POST["text"];  
    $column_name = $_POST["column_name"]; 
    $sql = "UPDATE agents SET ".$column_name."='".$text."' WHERE id='".$id."'";  

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))  
    {  
        echo 'Data Updated';  
    }  
?>
```

select.php - this is where the datatable comes from

```
<td class="address" data-id4="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td> 
<td>
     <select class="gender" onchange="getval(this)" data-id5="'.$row["id"].'" >
                    <option value="Male" ' . ( $row["gender"]=='Male' ? 'selected' : '' ) . '>Male</option>
                    <option value="Female" ' . ( $row["gender"]=='Female' ? 'selected' : '' ) . '>Female</option>
                 </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Where have you defined `getval`?

Comment: Only two genders. I'm offended! You need non binary lesbian seagull you monster! You need to provide the code for `getVal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var gender = $(this).value();` to `var gender = $(this).val();`

Comment: thanks! it works now.